# What does "bang" mean in this phrase?

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang, translation, north-american-english

The sentence:

> I thought you said you was innocent, Carl? That you don't bang?

I'm playing a game that this word appears, and I want to know in a gang context what does that word mean, can someone please answer that question

I've posted some screenshots that contains the main context for this question.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

[image: image 5]

If the screenshot is not enough I've posted a link of a youtube video that contains this quote.

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgxsc2XyEg4

•The sentence is on the minute                   [2:56]

•The beginning of the context is on the minute  [2:05]

Answer (score 2):

**Bang** as a verb here appears to be an unfortunate back-formation from [gang bangers](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gangbanger).

> M-W: "a member of a street gang"
>
> Example Sentence -> The ... DEA needs to focus more on the kingpins of the drug trade and less on the gangbangers in the street.

*That you don't bang* would mean that you're no gang member.

(For an example of a back-formed verb, compare liaison -> liaise.)

Comment: [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bang&page=2) has a lot of definitions for bang relating to sex, but also "part of a gang/ particpates in gang activites" and "to shoot".

Comment: Yes, place *bang* as coming directly from gang bang (group rape). But gang bangers (thugs, not rapists) triggers this use of bang as a verb for acting with a gang.